# Is "forced" technology transfer against the WTO TRIPS agreement?

Tags: international-law, international, wto

Is "forced" technology transfer against WTO TRIPS agreement? The TRIPS agreement state that it's an agreement that seeks to help both users and producers benefit from the agreement through technology transfer and protection and enforcement of property rights.

> The general goals of the TRIPS Agreement are contained in the Preamble
>   of the Agreement, which reproduces the basic Uruguay Round negotiating
>   objectives established in the TRIPS area by the 1986 Punta del Este
>   Declaration and the 1988/89 Mid-Term Review. These objectives include
>   the reduction of distortions and impediments to international trade,
>   promotion of effective and adequate protection of intellectual
>   property rights, and ensuring that measures and procedures to enforce
>   intellectual property rights do not themselves become barriers to
>   legitimate trade. These objectives should be read in conjunction with
>   Article 7, **entitled “Objectives”, according to which the protection
>   and enforcement of intellectual property rights should contribute to
>   the promotion of technological innovation and to the transfer and
>   dissemination of technology, to the mutual advantage of producers and
>   users of technological knowledge and in a manner conducive to social
>   and economic welfare, and to a balance of rights and obligations.**
>   Article 8, entitled “Principles”, recognizes the rights of Members to
>   adopt measures for public health and other public interest reasons and
>   to prevent the abuse of intellectual property rights, provided that
>   such measures are consistent with the provisions of the TRIPS
>   Agreement.

However, it doesn't say how the technology should be transferred anywhere. So is China's "forced" technology transfer legal under the TRIPS agreement?

Comment: What is China's actual rule here? This is likely to devolve into a question of what "forced" means when companies voluntarily contract with Chinese subcontractors...